# App Terminating Due to Unavailable PixelFormat Type on an AVCaptureConnection

Tags: ios, swift, avcapturesession, ios-camera

I am trying to set the Pixel format type on an AVCaptureConnection but it terminates for all the RGB settings but works for the kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA.

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', 
reason: '*** -[AVCaptureVideoDataOutput setVideoSettings:] Unsupported 
pixel format type - use -availableVideoCVPixelFormatTypes'
```

The code that produces this error is this:

```
let settings: [AnyHashable: Any] = [kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey as AnyHashable: kCVPixelFormatType_30RGB]
output.videoSettings = settings as! [String : Any]
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out!

I looked at the available PixelFormats on that camera and found that it only supports three different types of pixel formats..

420f, BGRA, and 420v